# How to change polygon shape in CAShapeLayer by tapping its corners?

Tags: iphone, caanimation, cashapelayer

I am drawing a CAShapeLayer with a polygon with 8 corners. I want to change the shape of the polygon by dragging one or multiple corners at a time. How can i achieve this?

CHeers
AF

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i have not got a solution for this yet. I kept trying different things but the only thing that slightly worked for me, which is not optimal, is to apply the transformation of the corners as multiple animations applied on the path.